# How to detect when text overflows/wraps a Kinetic.Text?

Tags: javascript, kineticjs

One of the requirements for some code I'm working on is to detect when the text in a Kinetic.Text box is too long and overflows/wraps and decrease the fontsize so it fits (horizontally).

I can't seem to determine when text would overflow/wrap in a Kinetic.Text.

The fontsize is the height of the text area. None of getHeight() getTextHeight() or lineHeight() seem to change when text starts to overflow/wrap.

Comment: @mjhm: actually Heinrich's downvoted and now deleted answer did provide a correct but incomplete answer to the question.  By adding each word in a sentence and then comparing the new text width with the box width you can determine where a newline breakpoint should be inserted into the sentence.

Comment: @markE I did experiment with this, but it was unreliable. the textwidth would never be greater than the width of the kinetic.text. When adding characters to the text, the textwidth would either stop on, or before the actual width. It would be nice if the textwidth was the real textwidth instead of the apparent/rendered width, then it would just be a nice easy check if it was greater than the width.

Comment: I posted an answer on how to wrap Kinetic.Text by using measureText.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The html canvas context has a measureText method that will measure the width of specified text.

Here's an example that adds a changeText method to Kinetic.Text.

The changeText method causes specified text to be wrapped by adding newline characters when the text would exceed a maxLineWidth.

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/MTQRV/

```
// create an offscreen canvas

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// create a Kinetic.Text object

var wrappedText = new Kinetic.Text({
    x: 10,
    y: 30,
    fill: 'black',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontFamily: "Verdana",
    text: "testing..."
});

// add a maxLineWidth property to the text node

wrappedText.maxLineWidth = 250; // pixels

// add a changeText method to the text node 
// this method will wrap the specified text
// within maxLineWidth by adding newline characters

wrappedText.changeText = function (text) {

    var maxLength = this.maxLineWidth;
    ctx.font = this.getFontSize() + " " + this.getFontFamily();
    var words = text.split(" ");
    var wrapped = "";
    var line = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (ctx.measureText(line + " " + words[i]).width > maxLength) {
            wrapped += (line + "\n");
            line = "";
        }
        line += " " + words[i];
    }
    wrapped += line;
    this.setText(wrapped);
    layer.draw();
}
layer.add(wrappedText);

// TESTING

wrappedText.changeText(someText);

layer.draw();
```